# C# Trying to Obfuscate a Number via Parsing

Tags: c#

here's my current code that I am using

```
        public string obfuscateNums(string src)
    {
        string returnSrc = src;
        string[] numbers = Regex.Split(src, @"\D+");
        foreach (string val in numbers)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
            {
                string newNum = obfuscateNumber(val);
                Regex reg = new Regex(val);
                returnSrc = reg.Replace(returnSrc, newNum);
            }
        }
        return returnSrc;
    }
    public string obfuscateNumber(string origNumber)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int orig = Convert.ToInt32(origNumber);
        int add = random.Next(0, orig * 2);
        int sub = add;
        int mul = random.Next(0, orig * 2);
        int div = mul;

        return "((((" + orig + " + " + add + ")-" + sub + ")*" + mul + ")/" + div + ")";
    }
```

Before it would only obfuscate the last number but now it's obfuscating numbers inside of the already obfuscated number. Anyone know how I would fix this?

Current Result:

```
local x = ((((27 + ((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0)1)-((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0)1)*((((3 + ((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))-((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))*0)/0))/((((3 + ((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))-((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))*0)/0)) + ((((29 + ((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0)((((4 + 7)-7)*0)/0))-((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0)((((4 + 7)-7)*0)/0))*((((4 + 7)-7)*0)/0))/((((4 + 7)-7)*0)/0)) + ((((28 + ((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0)((((3 + ((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))-((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))*0)/0))-((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0)((((3 + ((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))-((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))*0)/0))*((((3 + ((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))-((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))*0)/0))/((((3 + ((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))-((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))*0)/0)) + ((((26 + ((((4 + 7)-7)*0)/0)9)-((((4 + 7)-7)*0)/0)9)*((((3 + ((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))-((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))*0)/0))/((((3 + ((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))-((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))*0)/0)) + ((((3 + ((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))-((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0))*0)/0) + ((((4 + 7)-7)*0)/0) + ((((5 + 9)-9)*0)/0)
```

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: Well you are doing the transformation one time for every loop in the line `returnSrc = reg.Replace(returnSrc, newNum);` This will transform your already made transformations if they match `val`

Comment: @mortb yea I'm trying to figure out how to fix it rn

Comment: @Voided then ask the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `obfuscateNums` to:

```
var returnSrc = src;
var numbers = Regex.Split(src, @"\D+");
var lastIndex = 0;

foreach (var val in numbers)
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
    {
         var newNum = ObfuscateNumber(val);
         var startIndex = returnSrc.IndexOf(val, lastIndex);
         if (startIndex == -1) continue;

         returnSrc = returnSrc.Remove(startIndex, val.Length);
         returnSrc = returnSrc.Insert(startIndex, newNum);
         lastIndex = startIndex + newNum.Length;
     }

return returnSrc;
```

Comment: thanks for this, it worked, i was trying a super complicated approach, but thanks for the more simple one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the overload of `Regex.Replace(...)` that takes a `MatchEvaluator` for this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx

Like so:

```
public string obfuscateNums(string src)
{
    string returnSrc = src;
    var reg = new Regex(@"\d+");
    return reg.Replace(src, (match) => obfuscateNumber(match.Value));
}

public string obfuscateNumber(string origNumber)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int orig = Convert.ToInt32(origNumber);
    int add = random.Next(0, orig * 2);
    int sub = add;
    int mul = random.Next(0, orig * 2);
    int div = mul;

    return "((((" + orig + " + " + add + ")-" + sub + ")*" + mul + ")/" + div + ")";
}
```

The `MatchEvaluator` method parameter is a method that processes each match and returns a replacement value.

Comment: This `Regex.Replace(...)`overload is a bit unknown, so I try to spread the knowledge. It is good for many things